# Need to sort custom hash map based on value(Login time)

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

I am using struts, web service(rest) in my project.

In my action class(named as AdminMgmtAction below) I am getting a hashMap object(activeUserMap) by using rest API (getMdmServiceBO().getLockBO().getAllActiveUsers();) which is stored in ActiveUserMap which again extending a hashMap whose key is String and value is ActiveUserVO as given below. My requirement is to sort based on loggedInTime.

I have tried by using comparator interface and linkedHashMap which maintain order but its not working. Can anybody please suggest me.

```
public class AdminMgmtAction extends BaseAction {
    public ActionForward showActiveUsers(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
        dlog.debug("Executing showActiveUsers method in AdminMgmtAction...");
        ActionForward forward = null;
        AdminMgmtForm adminMgmtForm = (AdminMgmtForm) form;

        try {
            // get the active user map
            ActiveUserMap activeUserMap = getMdmServiceBO().getLockBO().getAllActiveUsers();
            //LinkedHashMap<String, ActiveUserVO> lm = new LinkedHashMap<String, ActiveUserVO>(activeUserMap);
            adminMgmtForm.setAllActiveUsersMap(activeUserMap);
            adminMgmtForm.setSelectedUidNSessId(null);

            return mapping.findForward(AdminConstants.SHOW_ACTIVE_USERS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            flog.fatal("System Exception Occured: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            return mapping.findForward(MDMConstants.FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

public class ActiveUserMap extends LinkedHashMap<String, ActiveUserVO> {

    /**
     * Changed hashMap to LinkedHashMap
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2584709276177374330L;

    public ActiveUserMap() {
        super();
    }

}

public class ActiveUserVO implements Serializable, Comparable<ActiveUserVO>{
    /**
     * Implement comparable
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6501714930988894286L;

    private String sessionId;
    private int userId;
    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String emailAddress;
    private boolean aquiredLock;
    private Date loggedInTime;

    public Date getLoggedInTime() {
        return loggedInTime;
    }
    public void setLoggedInTime(Date loggedInTime) {
        this.loggedInTime = loggedInTime;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ActiveUserVO o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return o.getLoggedInTime().compareTo(this.loggedInTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [java.util.TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

It is a Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation. The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used...

Create your `TreeMap` that maps Dates to `ActiveUserVO`. Assuming the Date object you are using already implements `Comparable`, then you don't even need to write your own in the ActiveUserVO class.

**Note**: You may not need this extra class, but I put the declaration in case you still want to use it.

```
public class ActiveUserMap extends TreeMap<Date, ActiveUserVO>
{
}
```

Instead, you could just iterate through the map you get back from the API call and place them into a TreeMap.

**For example**,

```
// create a sorted map
TreeMap<Date, ActiveUserVO> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Date, ActiveUserVO>();

// get the active user map
ActiveUserMap activeUserMap = getMdmServiceBO().getLockBO().getAllActiveUsers();

// Iterate through the keys of the activeUserMap
// I don't know the exact implementation of this map - hence the pseudocode
for (each key in activeUserMap)
{
   ActiveUserVO auVO = activeUserMap.get(key);
   sortedMap.put(auVO.getDate(), auVO);
}
```

Comment: Perfect !! Michael, it works I really appreciate your help.

The date was coming in descending order I just modified like below

NavigableMap<Date, ActiveUserVO> nMap = sortedMap.descendingMap();

Thanks again.